# Why is springboot th:selected not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a simple Spring Boot application about Contact Manager.Th:selected attribute not working on view edit page.Please help me.

Contorller

```
    @GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable("id")long id) {
        Contact contact = contactService.get(id);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("edit.html");
        PhoneList phoneList = new PhoneList(contact.getPhones());


        modelAndView.addObject("contact", contact);
        modelAndView.addObject("form", phoneList);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

edit.html

```
 <div th:object="${form}">
                <div class="form-group" th:each="phone, itemStat : ${form.phones}">


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="type" id="type">
                            <option th:each="typeOpt : ${T(ru.murik.phone_book3.models.Type).values()}"
                                    th:value="${typeOpt}"
                                    th:text="${typeOpt}"
                                    th:selected="${phone.getPhoneType().getType()} == ${typeOpt}">
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <p th:text="${phone.getPhoneType().getType()}"></p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>


                    <!--                    <label for="phoneNumber" th:text="${phone.phoneType.type}"></label>-->
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{phones[__${itemStat.index}__].phoneNumber}" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" >
                    <br>
                    <br>

                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
 </div>
```